# Why am i getting syntax error or access violation?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

When i am trying to insert something to database i am getting syntax error.I have this following code but i don't really know what i am doing wrong.

```
if(isset($_POST['imadbID']) || isset($_POST['comment'])|| isset($_POST['Title']) || isset($_POST['Year'])
|| isset($_POST['released']) || isset($_POST['Runtime'])|| isset($_POST['Actors'])||isset($_POST['Country']) || isset($_POST['Language'])
|| isset($_POST['Plot']) || isset($_POST['Poster']) || isset($_POST['Director']) || isset($_POST['Writer']) || isset($_POST['imdbRating']) || isset($_POST['tst'])){
    $imdbid=json_decode($_POST['imdbID']); $comment=json_decode($_POST['comment']);
    $title=json_decode($_POST['Title']);   $year=json_decode($_POST['Year']);   $released=json_decode($_POST['Released']);
$runtime=json_decode($_POST['Runtime']);   $actor=json_decode($_POST['Actors']);  $country=json_decode($_POST['Country']);
$lang=json_decode($_POST['Language']);   $plot=json_decode($_POST['Plot']);   $poster=json_decode($_POST['Poster']);
$director=json_decode($_POST['Director']);  $writer=json_decode($_POST['Writer']);  $rating=json_decode($_POST['imdbRating']);
 $test=json_decode($_POST['tst']);
    }
try {
$sql="INSERT INTO films (title,length,description,releasedate,bannerpath,language,imdbid,country,rating)
VALUES ($title,$runtime,$plot,$released,$poster,$lang,$imdbid,$country,$rating)";
$conn->exec($sql);
$film_id=$conn->lastInsertId($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

i have browsed other question and answer related to this but can't seem to find a solution.

the error i am getting

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ',,,,,,,6.5)' at line 2

Comment: You're using PDO and you don't bind the parameters to a prepared statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of quotes is probably the reason for the syntax error, however you're using PDO in a way that is unsafe, you might as well go back to using `mysql_*`

Try this..

```
$sql=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO films (title,length,description,releasedate,bannerpath,language,imdbid,country,rating)
VALUES (:t,:r,:p,:re,:po,:s,:i,:c,:ra)");
$sql->execute(array(":t"=>$title, ":r"=>$runtime, ":p"=>$plot, ":re"=>$released, ":po"=>$poster,":s"=>$lang,":i"=>$imdbid, ":c"=>$country, ":ra"=>$rating));
```

Comment: used your code everything is fine except for title and everything is returning null.can't find out why

Comment: var_dump all the variables you're insertng and make sure they arent null or empty before inserting.

Comment: yeah they are null .

Comment: only the rating column isn't NULL.I have no idea why are the rest null :/

Comment: well if you did a var dump and they are showing up as null then of course they will still be null when you insert them. you would have to post the full code for anyone to give you a definitive answer why, but that would be a new question.